Telegram Bot use_context problem when try to start
I try to make a telegram bot with using VSCode. My telegram bot code is
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters
import requests

texts = {"a": "", "b": "", "c": ""}

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Hello! Send /set a, b, or c followed by the text to set.')

def set_text(update, context):
    try:
        key = context.args[0]
        text = " ".join(context.args[1:])
        if key in texts:
            texts[key] = text
            update.message.reply_text(f'Text for {key} set to: {text}')
            
            # HTTP POST request to C# application
            url = "http://localhost:5000/settext"
            payload = {"key": key, "text": text}
            requests.post(url, data=payload)
        else:
            update.message.reply_text('Invalid key. Use a, b, or c.')
    except IndexError:
        update.message.reply_text('Usage: /set [a|b|c] [text]')

def main():
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("set", set_text))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I got an error when try to start bot. Python version is 3.12.0 python-telegram-bot version is 21.3
Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Users\SLap\source\repos\CrypTechTool\CrypTechTool\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\telegram\bot.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Users\SLap\source\repos\CrypTechTool\CrypTechTool\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\telegram\bot.py", line 27, in main
    updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

Can you help me anyone ? I use ChatGPT and search on google. No result

I want to start this bot but i got an error when i try to start.

Does this answer your question? TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

According to the python-telegram-bot package's documentation the Updater class does not accept use_context parameter. So, in turn your code will not work.
Please check the the examples listed in official documentation website for the correct usage.
